# ComboBox ItemSource ObservationCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box that have item source that bind to observation collection and with Data-template as the item-template. I have a problem when i click at the combo box .value and it doesn't show the value of the selected value in the combo box

Below is my Data Template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ColorCode}" Width="30"  Height="15"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorName}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

</DataTemplate>
```

Below is my combo box:

```
    <ComboBox Name="cmbAccentColors" Grid.Column="1"  Width="130" Height="20" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboColorData}}"
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" MaxDropDownHeight="120"
                              SelectionChanged="cmbColors_SelectionChanged"
 >

    Private void cmbColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsLoaded)
            {
                return;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(cmbAccentColors.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add DisplayMemberPath to your combobox. DisplayMemberPath specifies the path.

DisplayMemberPath = "YourProperty";

Also this how you access the selected Item,

```
Private void cmbColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.Text;    
}
```

Comment: But it said cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate.

Comment: @user3639591 why do you need to set  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"

Comment: @Sajeeetharan Because i have Rectangle of colors. inside the combobox.. Where inside the combobox got Rectangle and Textblock.